# Angular component UI

Tags: angular

I'm building an Angular app and facing a design issue.

I've got 2 main components, Lobby and Game, each containing 3 child components.

the Lobby component's HTML looks like that:

```
<div class='lobby-container' fxLayout="column">
    <div fxFlex="10">
        <lobby-header></lobby-header>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="90" fxLayout="row">
        <lobby-user-table fxFlex="70" (startMatch)=" startNewMatch()"></lobby-user-table>
        <lobby-activities fxFlex="30"></lobby-activities>
    </div>
</div>
```

It contains a lobby-header (width: 100%). and below there are 2 additional child components horizontally,
lobby-user-table of width:70% and lobby-activities of 30%.

The Game component is similar to Lobby component, it has 3 children as well:

```
<div class='game-container' fxLayout="column">
    <div fxFlex="10">
        <game-header></game-header>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="90" fxLayout="row">
        <game-table fxFlex="70" (startMatch)=" startNewMatch()"></game-table>
        <game-activities fxFlex="30"></game-activities>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to replace two child components (lobby-activities and game-activities) with an independent and general Activities component instead, which will always be displayed. so routing from Lobby to Game and back won't effect the new Activities component and yet, keep the current UI.

I use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to display the routed parent component.

I can't figure a way to display the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` along side the new Activities component and keep the current design.

**UPDATE:**

To make things a bit clearer I added an illustration of the desired UI.

[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @DavisJahn How to build the HTML with the router-outlet and the new Activity component that will display the routed component (Lobby or Game) together with the Activity component and preserve the required UI

Comment: You are better off ditching the flex stuff for grid and grid areas.

Comment: @JohnPeters  that is actually not the issue, but anyways, what is wrong with flex for container measurements?

Comment: Grid is superior, it allows for x and y coordinates as well as spans and areas.  I don't use Flex any more. Also here's an answer for child routing : https://dev.to/jwp/please-help-me-understand-child-routing-in-angular-3agbtes.